# asp.net forms authentification security issues

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

I have a kind of asp.net forms authentication with the code like that:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(account.Id.ToString(), true);
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(account.Id.ToString()), null);
```

What kind of additional efforts shall I take  to make authentication cookie (that is user id) more securable? (https, encoding for example)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get high security you should enable ssl in your web.config:

Comment: Shall I use FormsAuthentication.Encrypt/Decrypt and what is best practice if I want to use not securable http?

Comment: You should use "Validation" in protection section.
See here for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the article. I read that "Protection" has "All" option by default (with encoding and this option is recommended). Does it mean I shall take no additional effort to make my cookie securable (for http) ?

Comment: If you choose "All" you don't have to secure your cookies anymore because the got encrypted.